# Why don't two multinormal draws match when using same, but reversed, mean vector and covariance?

Tags: python, numpy, random, statistics

I'm hoping to understand why two draws from a multinormal distribution, with the same but reordered mean vector (and correctly reordered covariance vector) differ when the covariance is exponential.

This MWE should explain better than that:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)
x0 = [1,2,3]
y0 = np.diag([0.3, 0.5, 0.7])
z0 = np.random.multivariate_normal(x0, y0)

np.random.seed(10)
x1 = [3,2,1]
y1 = np.diag([0.7, 0.5, 0.3])
z1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(x1, y1)

print (np.allclose(z0, np.flip(z1))) # True, as expeceted

np.random.seed(10)
z0 = np.random.multivariate_normal(x0, np.exp(y0))
np.random.seed(10)
z1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(x1, np.exp(y1))

# these are unexpectedly different
print (z0, z1)
print (z0.mean(), z1.mean())
```

Is that difference mathematical, or numeric, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have nothing to do with np.exp(). For example,

```
np.random.seed(11)
y0 = np.exp(y0)
y0[y0==1] = 0
z0 = np.random.multivariate_normal(x0, y0)
np.random.seed(11)
y1 = np.exp(y1)
y1[y1==1] = 0
z1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(x1, y1)
```

It appears as though their is a random interaction between the rows and columns that updates the random-seed value. Meaning that if you have an array with non-zero off-diagonal entries, then that causes a non-random decision of both row and column that is not reversible, which in turn forms a different path in using the random-seed value. When I fix all the off-diagonal values to zero, then the same random-seed values are generated.

**Update (further explanation):**

Think about it this way, if I say to pick from a random row in `y0 = np.diag([0.7,0.5,0.3])` then SEED is consulted and updated and I pick say `(0.7,0,0)` now I ask to pick a random variable, but two values are zero, so SEED is not consulted since there is only one outcome. Thus, 0.7 is chosen and the same would happen in the flipped case. However, in the case of `y0 = np.exp(np.diag([0.7,0.5,0.3]))` it is a different story. In both the forward and reversed setups the 0.7 might be chosen, but in the first case it is a (E**0.7,1,1) and in the second it is a (1,1,E**0.7) which don't have a guaranteed second choice. Hence, the SEED will be consulted and updated a second time based on these two different vectors, sending SEED to run down two completely different paths.

Comment: that doesn't sound quite right, see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/random/mtrand.pyx#L4118 for what's going on inside.  it just generates N independent gaussian variates, then multiples them by the inverse of the covariance matrix.  I think the difference is just that the algorithm is arbitrarily picking one side of the SVD, and this breaks the symmetry the OP expects

Comment: Clearly it is the positioning of the 1's that is causing a difference. Whether that is achieved through some selection or some multiplication is simply a procedural difference in how to think about the problem. The result is the same. If you are going to put in the work and dive into the specifics of the code, feel free to post a more detailed answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks! The specifics aren't of too much importance to me, just wanted a general idea of what was going on (and to make sure I wasn't missing something fundamental).

Comment: @ccap89 I've just been playing a bit and think my idea isn't quite right.  that said, I'd consider the interaction between the seed and sampled values to be an implementation artifact and hence not rely on it, a unit test of something small might be OK but not much more

Comment: @Sam Mason I agree. I would almost say that this is a bug and is unexpected behavior. In general, one should not desire collisions in their RNG; i.e., starting at two different starts, but ending with the same result. This is normally considered a bug.